# How to create a table with multiple columns in ios

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, storyboard, viewcontroller, tablelayout

I am a beginner in xamarin ios, I want to create a table with 3 columns and multiple rows, and the no of row is depends on the data coming from the API .How can I do this...

Please help me...

I want to create the table like this...[image]

Comment: You would need to use a UICollectionView and configure it based on the data fed into the view source

Answer (score 3):

You can simulate drawing the chart by following steps.

1. Custom `TableHeaderView` with three black rectangle ,just need add three label with its black border.
2. Do the same work as step1 with `TableViewCell`, and then place a textfield in first rectangle, place a button and a label in second rectangle,place two button in third rectangle.

#### Sample Code

`TableHeaderView`

```
public class headerView : UIView
{
    public headerView()
    {
        this.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 50);

        nfloat width = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width / 3;

        UILabel title = new UILabel();
        title.Text = "Title";
        title.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
        title.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        title.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(20);
        title.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
        title.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
        title.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, width, 50);
        this.Add(title);

        UILabel File = new UILabel();
        File.Text = "File";
        File.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
        File.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        File.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(20);
        File.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
        File.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
        File.Frame = new CGRect(width, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width / 3, 50);
        this.Add(File);

        UILabel Option = new UILabel();
        Option.Text = "Option";
        Option.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
        Option.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        Option.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(20);
        Option.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
        Option.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
        Option.Frame = new CGRect(width * 2, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width / 3, 50);
        this.Add(Option);
    }
}

table.TableHeaderView = new headerView();
```

`TableViewCell`

```
public CustomVegeCell (NSString cellId) : base (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
    {
        SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Gray;

        nfloat width = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width / 3;

        UIView headingLabel = new UIView();
        headingLabel.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
        headingLabel.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
        headingLabel.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, width, 100);


        UIView subheadingLabel = new UIView();
        subheadingLabel.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
        subheadingLabel.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
        subheadingLabel.Frame = new CGRect(width, 0, width, 100);

        UIView imageView = new UIView();
        imageView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
        imageView.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
        imageView.Frame = new CGRect(width *2, 0, width, 100);

        ContentView.Add (headingLabel);
        ContentView.Add (subheadingLabel);
        ContentView.Add (imageView);

        ///add additional control here
    }
```

[image]

Comment: @Xia-MSFT I want to add rows when clicking the plus button and remove the specified row when clicking the minus button .., how can I do that.

Comment: @AswathyKR It is another question, can you open a new thread ?It can be helpful for others to search.

Comment: @Xia-MSFT Ok , I am added a new thread, could you please help to solve my issue.. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50814633/how-to-add-and-remove-rows-in-a-uitableview-dynamically-in-xamarin-ios